# Image/Drawbale/CustomView in a NumberPicker

Tags: android, android-layout, numberpicker

Is there any way to use the android NumberPicker to scroll through images (with or without the text)

I've tried to extend the NumberPicker and get the EditText from it

```
(EditText v = (EditText) getChildAt(0)) ;
```

Then I tried to set a background drawable or a CompoundDrawable.

But the images are only displayed when the EditText is in editmode, otherwise they're hidden. 
Any idea how to create a NumberPicker with images?

Comment: https://android-arsenal.com/tag/157 might be a good place to start

Comment: I don't need an image picker for pictures from the device, I want to use the NumberPicker (wheel) with images instead of text/numbers.